# how to pops and returns the character at the top of the Stack?

Tags: java

```
Stack s=new Stack();
LinkedList qeue = new LinkedList();

public void pushCharacter(char ch) {
    s.push(ch);
}
public void enqueueCharacter(char ch) {
    qeue.addLast(ch);
}
public char popCharacter() {
    s.pop();
    return  // ?11
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return s.pop();
```

[`Stack#pop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#pop()) "removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function". You must have a `Stack<Character>`, though. [Don't use raw types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Just to note this he also needs to cast it to `char` in this case since that is his return type for the method and he is using `Stack` not `Stack<Character>`, or just define it correctly as `Stack<Character>` since thats what he wants anyway.